# "Canonical Path" Function in XQuery?

Tags: xquery

Is there an standard XQuery function that will return a 'canonical' path for a node?
I mean something like:

> /root/element/sub-element[0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *XQuery 3.0* there is [`fn:path($node)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-path), which does exactly that. If it is not supported by your query processor, you can also use *FunctX*'s [`functx:path-to-node-with-pos($node)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_path-to-node-with-pos.html), which unfortunately does not play well with namespaces.

Comment: Here's an example of fn:path() in action: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#kZKJchkcaEujMQ00vGwZl3+PFZs= It uses the EQName syntax for having a path expression independent of the prolog declarations.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in the predicate of a path expression using XQuery you can do something like:

```
doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book[substring(title,1,5)='Harry']
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question (or I have misunderstood your answer): I meant 'given a node, can I construct another XPATH query that can be used to refer to it in a 'canonical format'. (I could have matched it in several ways, but now I want to store a simple unambigous pointer to it).